# ASP.NET MVC Connection String

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

My website, an ASP.NET MVC app, is working perfectly inside Visual Studio with database entities and such. I want to try to upload my app to GoDaddy's Plesk Web Service.

I got a guide here:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-host-your-asp-net-mvc-website-on-godaddy-server/

which says at step 19: "Write Connection String for your server side database."
and at step 20 "Open Visual Studio again and update database from package manager, again writing same connection string in web.config of your project in Visual Studio. Open package manager console and type the following command,"

Can anyone of you please give me some advice what it means by connection string?

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/connection-strings-explained/

Comment: its located in Web.config, you just need to update with the correct values for the remove server on GoDaddy, like the server's ip address, user, password and database name

Comment: Package Manager Console is in `Tools/NuGet Package Manager/Package Manager Console`

Comment: Location to insert your connection string in config file is `<configuration><appSettings>......blah, blah..</appSettings><connectionStrings><add name="myConnection" connectionString = "Data Source=xxx.......blah, blah"/></connectionStrings></configuration>`

Comment: There is no Connection Strings in web.config.

Comment: you need to add it there

Answer (score 1):

There is  connection string in web.config file.
I am using entity framework so my connection string is as per below

> <**add name="yourEntityName"** connectionString="metadata=res://*/entity.csdl|res://*/entity.ssdl|res://*/entity.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="**data source=yourServerIpAddress;****initial catalog=DataBaseName**;persist security info=True;**user id=YourId;password=YourPassword**;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

you have to change lines in your connection string where bold line in my conn. string.